# PutAsJsonAync not setting body properly

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm calling a 3rd party API right now. In post man I can do this, and it does what I'm expecting. Sets these two fields to "cancelled".

[image]

Here are the current headers in postman:
[image]

The verb that postman is using is PUT. POST is currently not supported by the API.
In code I'm doing this:

```
 var idcInput = new IdcInputParameters(
            status: "cancelled",
            ivrstatus: "cancelled"
        );

        // pass the updated parameters to RFS
        using HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await RfsApiClient.ApiClient.PutAsJsonAsync(uri, idcInput);

        var res = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Idc? idc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Idc>(res);
            return idc;
        }
```

The JsonSerializer outputs the following:

```
 "{\"status\":\"cancelled\",\"ivrstatus\":\"cancelled\"}"
```

I'm not 100% sure as to whats going on, but when I pass idcInput I'm getting back a 500 error from the API saying one or more input parameters is invalid. This leads me to believe that the body of the request is empty.

I've tried a lot of the answers on stack overflow however nothing's worked yet.

How do I set the body of the request to be a RAW Json object like postman?

Comment: Servers don't actually know what the client is doing to call them. They only know what data they have received from the client. So if you've got one client that works (Postman) and another client that doesn't work (your app) then something must be different about the requests. Observing the actual requests with a tool like Fiddler or Postman should help you figure out what's different. Don't assume your request body is empty - actually verify! Assumptions hurt when debugging. If our assumptions were right, everything would just work without issue from the start.

Comment: You have 9 headers shown in Postman for example, and we don't know what headers your app is sending. You havent shown the HTTP verb/method that Postman is using either. So even if your request body is 100% correct, you still must validate the other parts of the request.

Comment: @mason I've updated with postman headers.

Comment: Can you please add output of `JsonSerializer.Serialize(idcInput)` and the `IdcInputParameters` type?

Comment: @GuruStron here is the output of the JSONSerializer "{\"status\":\"cancelled\",\"ivrstatus\":\"cancelled\"}"

Comment: Okay - and when you view the requests using Fiddler or Wireshark or similar tool, what do you see?

Comment: I don't see you adding headers, are they setup on the client (`RfsApiClient.ApiClient`)?

Comment: @GuruStron yes the headers get added on the initialization of RfsApiClient.ApiClient.